# Git need to clone from a specific folder or remove top level folder, but keep contents from that folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to deploy a rails app via git, but my folder structure is a bit goofy b/c i created everything in an unnecessary folder like this:

```
MASTER
------ mysite
------------- app
------------- conf
------------- Gemfile
....
```

My git url looks like this:

```
git@subdomain.beanstalkapp.com:/mysite.git
```

How can i either clone a repository from inside the "mysite" folder, or how can i remove the "mysite folder" and move it's content into the master branch itself?

Comment: This isn't a Ruby or Rails question. It's a git question entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your `mysite` folder the only thing on its parent folder? If yes, you can move everything inside `mysite` folder to its parent folder. From the parent directory do:

```
mv -rf mysite/* .
rm -rf mysite
git add .
git commit -am 'removing mysite folder'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for this simple solution

Comment: Please, the is a mistake on the first line. Consider:
`mv mysite/* .`

Comment: `mv mysite/* .` would not move hidden files like `mysite/.gitignore` for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any hidden files (dotfiles like .gitignore), João Daniel's answer should be sufficient.

These commands should all cases I can think of (including moving dotfiles)

```
# Change dir into the root of the repo
cd ROOT_DIRECTORY_OF_YOUR_REPO

# Find all content directly under mysite, and execute
# git mv on them with the destination directory as the
# current directory
find mysite/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec git mv {} . \;

# Commit the change
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Git probably is not ideal for this, but you can probably do it with [sparseCheckout](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/).

"[Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/403664)" is a similar question with a good walkthrough of the steps.

Once you've cloned the sub-folder, you could delete the sparseCheckout configuration commit the root and then push back to master.